# How to add text in bottom of image using swiper slider

Tags: css, codeigniter, swiper.js

I want to make slider to my product with http://idangero.us/swiper/, i can control a image breakpoint with this code in javascript

```
breakpoints: {
        1024: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
          spaceBetween: 40,
        },
        768: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
          spaceBetween: 30,
        },
        640: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 20,
        },
        320: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
          spaceBetween: 10,
        }
      }
```

but my problem is when i want to add a text in bottom of image like this

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLfim.png)
i try use a @media screen and (min-width : 1024px) and function with this code

```
.swiper-slide .title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 210px;
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family: 'Mark Bold' !important;
  }
```

but the text is not responsive, if i change screen width the text is gone,

how to solved this problem? are swipper slider have a code for add text/caption in image?

Comment: Can you provide a code example of your current work status? What does “but the text is not responsive” mean? You've set fixed position and font-size in the CSS above –why did you do that? Can't you use dynamic units here (like em)? Are you really limited to that specific carousel? Because there are so many carousels outside on the web, that before you start implementing something on your own, you should use a carousel script that suits best to your use-case.

Comment: *Please refer this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826/348234) to learn about accepting answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*

Answer (score 1):

That's normal!
because you have put `@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)` i. e. when the screen exceeds 1024px displays this part of CSS.
maybe it is necessary to add other controls on the devices

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
@media screen and (min-width: 576px)
```

and you change the css code

Answer (score 0):

Try this for responsive css

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    .swiper-slide .title {
       position: absolute;
       top: 210px;
       left: 10px;
       color: white;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size:12pt;
       font-family: 'Mark Bold' !important;
     }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
        .swiper-slide .title {
           position: absolute;
           top: 210px;
           left: 10px;
           color: white;
           font-weight: bold;
           font-size:12pt;
           font-family: 'Mark Bold' !important;
         }
    }

 @media screen and (max-width:640px){
    .swiper-slide .title {
       position: absolute;
       top: 210px;
       left: 10px;
       color: white;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size:12pt;
       font-family: 'Mark Bold' !important;
     }
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px){
    .swiper-slide .title {
       position: absolute;
       top: 210px;
       left: 10px;
       color: white;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size:12pt;
       font-family: 'Mark Bold' !important;
     }
}
```